# can it be possible to render different layout based on condition android?

Tags: android, xml, layout, render

I have a video application where having 1 teacher and maximum 6 students. So can i show or render different layout for different number of students like:

```
1 teache 1 student = layoyt_1 (from xml)
1 teache 2 student = layoyt_2 (from xml)
1 teache 3 student = layoyt_3 (from xml)
1 teache 4 student = layoyt_4 (from xml)
1 teache 5 student = layoyt_5 (from xml)
1 teache 6 student = layoyt_6 (from xml)
```

based on number of students can i set different xml or layout? Please help.

Comment: yes, you can, but only on start... it would be better to have one XML with layout for all students and using `setVisibility` reduce number of unnecessary `View`s for not-present students. show how do you build your current layout (`Activity`/`Fragment` code + related XMLs)

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple ViewStubs in single layout where each ViewStub will contain layout for each condition and based on condition appropriate ViewStub is inflated!

ViewStub will be loaded only when you actually use it/need it(when setVisibility(int) or inflate() is invoked)

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub